# React JS with message "Model Parameter is Mandatory" displaying when creating app with npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My node version: 14.4.0
npm version: 6.14.8
create-react-app version: 3.4.1

I created a react app using "npx create-react-app my-app" command. But the webpage shows static content with message "Model parameter is mandatory"

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

I found out my mistake. I had added one script in the index.html and that was causing the issue. Silly of me :)